# Substitute or mock import of another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I want to test functions within `foo.js` using Jest without altering `foo.js`. I do *not* want to test native functions like `getBaseOs`. Simply importing a function from `foo.js` will evaluate all the import statements of `foo.js`. Any import that relies on native code will trigger an error and the test will not run.

Is there a way to substitute imports like `getBaseOs` but only within the test file, `foo.test.js`? I simply want to ignore `getBaseOs` within `foo.test.js` to allow testing. Is there a way to do that even if substitution is not the way?

```
// foo.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, } from 'react-native';
import { getBaseOs, } from 'react-native-device-info';

export default function foo(props) {
  return null;
}

// foo.test.js
import 'react-native';
import foo from './foo';

describe('test import substitution', () => {
  it('test getBaseOs', () => {
    const getBaseOs = jest.fn();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/636) by user karimo255 who commented on Jun 20, 2019.  Simply putting the code in `__mocks__/react-native-device-info.js` allows the code to be replaced in tests despite an import. I speculate that Jest imports files from `__mocks__` before performing a single test and matches the names of the files to the names of imports to match. Renaming the file will break it.

Here is the file that replaces the import statements of `react-native-device-info`, `__mocks__/react-native-device-info.js`:

```
export default {
  getBaseOs: () => 'A',
};
```